# Unable to merge linked lists?

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I'm trying to merge two linked lists, but for some reason, it says it's unable to read the value of null - when my value is defined.

```
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.length = 0;
  }

  add(value) {
    var node = new Node(value);
    var current;

    if (this.head == null) {
      this.head = node
    } else {
      current = this.head
      while (current.next) {
        current = current.next;
      }
      current.next = node
    }
    this.length++
  }
}

function mergeLinkedList(l1, l2) {
  let newList = new LinkedList()
  let currentNode1 = l1.head
  let currentNode2 = l2.head
  while (currentNode1 || currentNode2) {
    if (currentNode1.value <= currentNode2.value) {
      newList.add(currentNode1)
      newList.add(currentNode2)
    } else {
      newList.add(currentNode2)
      newList.add(currentNode1)
    }
    currentNode1 = currentNode1.next
    currentNode2.head = currentNode2.next
  }
  return newList
}

let l1 = new LinkedList()
l1.add(1)
l1.add(2)
l1.add(4)

let l2 = new LinkedList()
l2.add(1)
l2.add(3)
l2.add(4)

mergeLinkedList(l1, l2)
```

This is supposed to return a new linked list that's `1->1->2->3->4->4`, but instead returns an error when hitting this if statement: `if (currentNode1.value <= currentNode2.value)` stating that it cannot read property 'value' of null, but the value is clearly defined here.

Comment: Please add some sample input and output.

Comment: @JackBashford updated with input and outputs

Answer (score 0):

You have

> while (currentNode1 || currentNode2)

so that only requires one node to not be null to be in the while loop. But then after that you have

> if (currentNode1.value <= currentNode2.value)

which is accessing both the nodes' values. In this case you could be in the while loop with currentNode2 == null thus the error.

You should write your while loop condition as

```
 while (currentNode1 && currentNode2){
  .
  .
  .
 }
```

Then have another condition to check your linked list and append the rest of the one that is not yet null.

Comment: I realize what you mean, but I'm trying to take into account for the case that one list is longer than the other

Comment: You cannot access currentNodex.value if currentNodex is null. To account for the longer list, do another check for the currentNodex that is not yet at the end and append it to your newList.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the nodes independently and add the values instead of the node itself.

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }

    add(value) {
        var node = new Node(value);
        var current;

        if (this.head == null) {
            this.head = node
        } else {
            current = this.head
            while (current.next) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = node
        }
        this.length++
    }
}

function mergeLinkedList(l1, l2) {
    let newList = new LinkedList()
    let currentNode1 = l1.head
    let currentNode2 = l2.head
    while (currentNode1 && currentNode2) {
        if (currentNode1.value <= currentNode2.value) {
            newList.add(currentNode1.value)
            currentNode1 = currentNode1.next
        } else {
            newList.add(currentNode2.value)
            currentNode2 = currentNode2.next
        }
    }
    while (currentNode1) {
        newList.add(currentNode1.value)
        currentNode1 = currentNode1.next
    }
    while (currentNode2) {
        newList.add(currentNode2.value)
        currentNode2 = currentNode2.next
    }
    return newList
}

let l1 = new LinkedList()
l1.add(1)
l1.add(2)
l1.add(4)

console.log(l1);

let l2 = new LinkedList()
l2.add(1)
l2.add(3)
l2.add(4)

console.log(l2);

console.log(mergeLinkedList(l1, l2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

By looking above image:

```
var mergeTwoListss = function(l1, l2) {
    // initialize a dummy node, make a copy and iterate through with the copy. 
    // after iteration complete, you still have the reference to initial point
    const dummy=new ListNode()
    let tail= dummy
    // if you are comparing values in lists, make sure you have elements to compare 
    while (l1 && l2){
        if (l1.val<l2.val){
            tail.next=l1
            l1=l1.next
        }else{
            tail.next=l2
            l2=l2.next
        }
        tail=tail.next
    }
    // so far we have iterated for the same size of both nodes. what if one of them is longer. 
    if(l1){
        tail.next=l1
    }else if (l2){
        tail.next=l2
    }
    return dummy.next
    
};
```